# Repeated number when sequencing a list of subform items VBA code issue in Access 2010

Tags: vba, ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am new to VBA code so I may have not taken the most practical of approaches on the following situation. I have `Items` that is a subform to `Purchase_Orders`. One of the fields in `Items` is `PO_Line_item`. This has to be a sequence of numbers (from 1) where PO_ID is the same. If several items have the same PO_ID have then I need this sequence. I cannot use the Item_ID as they may not always be added in succession.

here's the code I used:

```
      Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)

        Dim db As Database
        Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
        Dim currentItem As String
        Dim seq As Long
        Dim sql As String

        sql = "SELECT * " & _
              "FROM Items " & _
              "WHERE PO_ID = " & Me.Parent.PO_ID


        Set db = CurrentDb
        Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(sql, dbOpenDynaset)


        rs.MoveFirst
        currentItem = ""
        With rs
            Do While Not .EOF

                If currentItem = "" Then
                   seq = 1
                   currentItem = seq
                Else
                    seq = currentItem + 1
                    currentItem = seq
                End If

                Me.PO_Line_Item = seq
                .MoveNext
            Loop

        End With
        Set rs = Nothing
        Set db = Nothing

    End Sub
```

This works great if I stay on the record, I get items 1 then 2 then 3. however if I return the form and input another item record then I get a repeat of the last `PO_Line_Item`. i.e. 1,2,3,(return to form)3,4.

If anyone knows why this is happening, or if there is an alternative method that I can use that will work as well; then ideas are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a recordset loop to find the number of elements - use SQL COUNT() instead.

```
sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) " & _
      "FROM Items " & _
      "WHERE PO_ID = " & Me.Parent.PO_ID
```

Or even shorter with the Access DCount function:

```
' Number of existing records (may be 0)
seq = DCount("Item_ID", "Items", "PO_ID = " & Me.Parent.PO_ID)
' assign the next number
Me.PO_Line_Item = seq + 1
```